# store class instances in scala maps/trie maps

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, shapeless

I am working on a feature to store classes (for example trained linear regression model of spark) in a map / trie map like implementation, so that I can retrieve it later whenever required.

I came up with a approach of code using serializer/serialization in scala where I convert the classes into `Array[Bytes]` and store it into a triemap and retrieve it later.

Was wondering if I can skip the conversion and directly store spark models into a single triemap.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way to do this is using PMML. You should save your trained model as a PMML model and then load it over a test data. Refer the link for an example on how to use a PMML model in spark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-pmml-model-export.html

Comment: I would be including classes from other libraries (like h20.ai) as well. So PMML may not be very good idea.